# Проблема в запросе mysql в codeignither

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Всем привет есть такой запрос (часть запроса)

```
$this->db->where('id_category',$cID);
            $this->db->where('id_subcategory',$scID);
            $this->db->where('visible',1);
            if(isset($filter_brand)):
                if(count($filter_brand)):
                    foreach ($filter_brand as $item):
                        foreach ($item as $item2):
                            $this->db->where('brand',$item2);
                        endforeach;
                    endforeach;

                endif;
            endif;

            $query = $this->db->get('tm_product_'.$city);
```

ЧТо тоже самое что и

```
SELECT *
FROM (`tm_product_almaty`)
WHERE `price` >= '2'
AND `price` <= '2111'
AND `id_category` =  '1'
AND `id_subcategory` =  '16'
AND `id_category` =  '1'
AND `id_subcategory` =  '16'
AND `visible` =  1
AND `brand` =  'ЭЛИТАН'
ORDER BY `title`
LIMIT 12
```

У меня проблема, когда я выбираю два бренда то генерируется запрос на подобие этого

```
AND `brand` =  'Бренд 1'
AND `brand` =  'Бренд 2'
```

а мне нужно что бы запрос был вот таким

```
SELECT *
FROM (`tm_product_almaty`)
WHERE `price` >= '2'
AND `price` <= '2111'
AND `id_category` =  '1'
AND `id_subcategory` =  '16'
AND `id_category` =  '1'
AND `id_subcategory` =  '16'
AND `visible` =  1
AND (`brand` =  'Брэнд 1'
or `brand` =  'Брэнд 2')
ORDER BY `title`
LIMIT 12
```

Как это реализовать

Comment: Почему бы не погуглить? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498693/codeigniters-where-and-or-where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас

```
foreach ($item as $item2):
```

`$item` Это массив, то тогда можете использовать

```
$this->db->where_in('brand', $item);
```

Примерный код будет таким

```
$this->db->where('id_category',$cID);

$this->db->where('id_subcategory',$scID);
$this->db->where('visible',1);
        if(isset($filter_brand)):
            if(count($filter_brand)):
                foreach ($filter_brand as $item):
                    $this->db->where_in('brand', $item);
                endforeach;
            endif;
        endif;

        $query = $this->db->get('tm_product_'.$city);
```

Answer (score 0):

Взято из [справки](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data):

> `$this->db->or_where()`
>
> This function is identical to the one above, except that multiple instances are joined by OR:
>
> `$this->db->where('name !=', $name);`
>
> `$this->db->or_where('id >', $id);  // Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' OR id > 50`